# ViberApp is existing in IONIC IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, viber

Now I'm developing IOS App and I want to check if the Viber App is existing in the Phone or not.

I already use `Viber:\\` URL scheme and https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-availability/ to check the app but the app is not detecting

There's any possible implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it by check if these is exist

`viber = "https://itunes.apple.com/ph/app/viber-messenger-chats-calls/id382617920?mt=8"`

and

use app-availability

`this.appAvailability.check(viber)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
 import { AppAvailability } from '@ionic-native/app-availability';
    import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

    constructor(private appAvailability: AppAvailability, private platform: Platform) { }

    let app;

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      app = 'Viber://';
    } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      app = 'com.viber.voip ';
    }

    this.appAvailability.check(app)
      .then(
        (yes: boolean) => console.log(app + ' is available'),
        (no: boolean) => console.log(app + ' is NOT available')
      );
```

Comment: i fixed it by check if these is exist viber = "https://itunes.apple.com/ph/app/viber-messenger-chats-calls/id382617920?mt=8" and use app-availability this.appAvailability.check(viber)

Answer (score 1):

the URLScheme must be declared publicly in Info.plist file first
visit [this UseYourLoaf tutorial](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/) for more details